# Including and excluding globbing patterns in bash

Tags: php, bash, wildcard, glob, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to use the [PHPCompatibility](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility) standard for [PHP CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) to test a specific set of files.

I'm currently using `find` to do this.

```
find ./path1 ./path2 ./path3 ./path4                                                \
    -type f                                                                         \
    -name '*.php'                                                                   \
    -not -path './path4/dontwantthis/*'                                             \
    -exec ./vendor/bin/phpcs                                                        \
    --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 5.6 {}                    \;
```

However, this is really slow and inefficient because the startup for the script runs for every single file.

The phpcs script takes in a path like `./vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 5.6 <path-of-your-php-files>` and I'd like to find a way to replicate the `find` stuff with a globbing pattern in place of the `<path-of-your-php-files>`

One of the major problems I was having was including `./path4/*.php` while also excluding `./path4/dontwantthis/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End your `-exec` option with `+` instead of `\;`. That tells `find` to run the command once with all the filenames, rather than separately for each filename.

```
find ./path1 ./path2 ./path3 ./path4                                                \
    -type f                                                                         \
    -name '*.php'                                                                   \
    -not -path './path4/dontwantthis/*'                                             \
    -exec ./vendor/bin/phpcs                                                        \
    --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 5.6 {} +
```